# The dot at enumerate list not at right place and also the line of the footnotes

Tags: lyx, lists, footnotes, enumerate, hebrew

I put here a .lyx file with two problems. I you can tell me how to fix them it will be great, I also put a picture of the output file (pdf)...

1. The the dot of the third level of the enumerate list is not at the right side...
2. The line of the footnotes is also not the right side.

Here is the LyX file:

```
%% LyX 2.2.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Simple CLM}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item א
\begin{enumerate}
\item ב
\begin{enumerate}
\item ג\footnote{דוגמא}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And here is the pdf output:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't look as if hebrew defines \roman in a suitable way. You should better use a different numbering for the third level.

Comment: It's LyX... This is the original output...

Comment: I know. But it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

The third level uses roman numbering. This apparently doesn't do LTR, in contrast to arabic numbering (used for the first level), that is redefined in Hebrew. You can redefine the label at the third level:

```
\renewcommand\labelenumiii{.\roman{enumiii}}
```

or use for example Hebrew numbering:

```
\renewcommand\labelenumiii{\hebrewnumeral{\value{enumiii}}.}
```

Comment: The first definition will put the dot in the right place, but the "number" itself will still be printed left to right: iv for 4. I'm not sure if this is the wanted result in hebrew.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. I noticed that, but I think it would be very strange to print roman numerals backwards. Basically roman is LTR and I think it should be kept. But I am not knowledgeable about the conventions about these things in Hebrew. I would expect them to be written LTR (if they use them at all), because arabic numbers are also written LTR.